# How to check if "Radiobutton" is checked?

Tags: java, android, radio-button, selected, checked

I would like to make a structure with the condition (if-else) `RadioButton`

I want that when the Radiobutton *RB1* is selected, this function is active:

```
regAuxiliar = ultimoRegistro;
```

And when the radiobutton *RB2* is selected, this function is active:

```
regAuxiliar = objRegistro;
```

And sorry for my English, I'm Brazilian.

Comment: Please refer to the API documentation of radio button widget (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioButton.html)

Answer (score 24):

Just as you would with a CheckBox

```
RadioButton rb;

rb = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rb);

rb.isChecked();
```

Answer (score 14):

```
        if(jRadioButton1.isSelected()){
            jTextField1.setText("Welcome");
        }
        else if(jRadioButton2.isSelected()){
            jTextField1.setText("Hello");
        }
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also maintain a flag value based on listener,

```
 radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {

                //handle the boolean flag here. 
                  if(arg1==true)
                         //Do something

                else 
                    //do something else

            }
        });
```

Or simply `isChecked()` can also be used to check the state of your RadioButton.

Here is a link to a sample,

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-radio-buttons-example/

And then based on the flag you can execute your function.

Answer (score 5):

`radiobuttonObj.isChecked()` will give you boolean

```
if(radiobuttonObj1.isChecked()){
//do what you want 
}else if(radiobuttonObj2.isChecked()){
//do what you want 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you need for espresso test the solutions is like this :

```
onView(withId(id)).check(matches(isChecked()));
```

Bye,

Answer (score 2):

`radioButton.isChecked()` function returns true if the Radion button is chosen, false otherwise.

[Source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioButton.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use switch like this:

XML Layout

```
<RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/RG"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/R1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_contnet"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="R1" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/R2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_contnet"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="R2" />
</RadioGroup>
```

And JAVA Activity

```
switch (RG.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {
        case R.id.R1:
            regAuxiliar = ultimoRegistro;
        case R.id.R2:
            regAuxiliar = objRegistro;
        default:
            regAuxiliar = null; // none selected
    }
```

You will also need to implement an onClick function with button or setOnCheckedChangeListener function to get required functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Solution

```
radioSection.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
          @Override
          public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group1, int checkedId1) {
              switch (checkedId1) {
                  case R.id.rbSr://radiobuttonID
                      //do what you want
                      break;
                  case R.id.rbJr://radiobuttonID
                      //do what you want
                      break;
              }
          }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if they're checked with the `el.checked` attribute.

[Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RadioNodeList/value) or this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/how-do-i-check-whether-a-checkbox-is-checked-in-jquery)

```js
let radio1 = document.querySelector('.radio1');
let radio2 = document.querySelector('.radio2');
let output = document.querySelector('.output');

function update() {
  if (radio1.checked) {
    output.innerHTML = "radio1";
  }
  else {
    output.innerHTML = "radio2";
  }
}

update();
```

```html
<div class="radios">
  <input class="radio1" type="radio" name="radios" onchange="update()" checked>
  <input class="radio2" type="radio" name="radios" onchange="update()">
</div>
<div class="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
   Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.radiobutton)).check(ViewAssertions.matches(isChecked()))
```