# Android: Why Radio Button in Radio Group always returns false for any item selected?

Tags: android, radio-button, android-radiogroup

I have two radio buttons in a radio group and when i select any of the radio button and try to get the boolean value using the isselected method then i always get the false value.
Why this is happening.Please help me.

Comment: Check for the **isChecked** property: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11050112/2649012

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem too, isSelected method didn't work.
The isChecked method worked for me:

`if( myRadioButton.isChecked() ){
        // do stuff
    } else {
        // do other stuff
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton btn, boolean isCheck) {

            //handle the boolean flag here. 
              if(isCheck==true)
                     //Do something

            else 
                //do something else

        }
    });
```

source: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11050112/2649012)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help

```
int radioButtonID = radioButtonGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
View radioButton = radioButtonGroup.findViewById(radioButtonID);
```

Then use the radioButton to perform whatever task you want.

Source : [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6440259/how-to-get-the-selected-index-of-a-radiogroup-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
int selectedRbBtn = radiogroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
```

If it returns `-1` then nothing was selected...