# Radio Button is selected java

Tags: java, android, radio-button

I'm trying to get that when a radio button within my app is selected, the application reloads. I've got the below code:

```
if(check.isSelected()== true){
    b1.setEnabled(true);
    finish();
    startActivity(getIntent());
}
```

However, the app doesn't seem to be entering the if statement even when the radio button is checked. Any ideas?

Comment: Use `check.isChecked()`.

Comment: This doesn't work either :(

Comment: where you have put this code and Try check.isChecked()

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050074/how-to-check-if-radiobutton-is-checked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this.

```
if(check.isChecked()){
    b1.setEnabled(true);
    startActivity(getIntent());
    finish();
}
```

You are using `startActivity` after finish called. Also change the if condition

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Doesn't seem to be working though.

Comment: What is the issue any crash or something? What is happening?

Comment: No crash at all the application just stays as it was making me think the if statement isn't being ran?

Answer (score 0):

Change you code as below. Use this

```
if(check.isChecked()== true){ 
}
```

instead of

```
if(check.isSelected()== true){ 
}
```

Comment: Still the same outcome :( doesn't appear to do anything